# Website is hitting a white page on login

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are similar questions out there, but I have tried all of the suggested solutions but still no luck. So my website is hitting a white page for some odd reason. I'm suspecting that .htaccess isn't working or the rewrite module is off. Having said that, I tested that by

`RewriteRule ^test$ http://google.com/ [R=302,L]`

and navigate to /test and works just fine.

On a side note, the website works just fine on a Localhost but not on a remote server.

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test$ http://google.com/ [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/.]+)$ index.php?route=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

IndexIgnore *

<Files "error_log.txt">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A white page generally means that your PHP script has encountered a fatal error and error reporting is not enabled. What is the status of the HTTP response you get?

Comment: Check your server error logs, there should be some information there.